# pg_restore throws error when trying to restore a table with constraints

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I try dumping tables from a production environment to a dev one. However, when dumping and restoring this table, using the following command:

`pg_restore --no-owner --no-acl --clean --if-exists -d database dump_file.dump`

I get an error stating that I can't drop that table unless I use something like CASCADE (i.e. dropping all other tables that depend on that one). Is there a way to determine the tables to be dropped? is there a way of maybe state in the `pg_dump` command to dump the table I'm looking to dump and all related tables ?

Here's the error raised:

> pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
> pg_restore: from TOC entry 4066; 2606 30526 CONSTRAINT table1 pkey user
> pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  cannot drop constraint pkey on table public.table1 because other objects depend on it
> DETAIL:  constraint id_fkey on table public.dag depends on index public.pkey
> constraint id_fkey on table public.dag depends on index public.pkey
> HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too...

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not seeing dumping/restoring a particular table. You are dumping/restoring the entire database.
2. If you want recreate the production database as a dev one then do:

```
pg_restore -C --no-owner --no-acl --clean --if-exists -d postgres dump_file.dump
```

The `-C`  with `--clean` will `DROP DATABASE db_name` and then rebuild it from scratch by connecting to the database `postgres` to do the `DROP/CREATE db_name` and then connect to `db_name` to load the rest of the objects.

This is the best way to clean out cruft and start at a consistent state.

**UPDATE**

1. Update your question with the `pg_dump` command so it is evident what you are doing.
2. If you want to see whether a particular table has dependencies, in the original database use `psql`  and do `\d the_table` to see what the dependencies to and from the table are. If you tell `pg_dump` to dump a single table it will dump just that table. It will not follow dependencies and dump those also. That is up to you to do.
3. Look into using a schema management tool to do your changes/migrations. I use [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) for this.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver for your answer, however supposedly I have only one table1 to migrate (as I don't want to dump and restore the whole database), and there is another table2 that is dependent on table1 key. Just to be sure, there is no other way to determine the dependent tables and dump and restore only these tables without modifying the rest of the database?

Comment: See **UPDATE**.

Answer (score -1):

You have a table on the dev database that has a pkey that is dependent and therefore can not be dropped before the restore. This is proper behavior.